# In silico PCR: any models that can quantitatively predict the initial content from the end amplified result?

Tags: pcr

Let's say I've run the PCR and I now have a certain amount of the amplicon product. Is there any model that infers how much of it was there before the PCR started? I suspect it should be a probabilistic model (a distribution) parameters (shape) of which will strongly depend on the details of the PCR protocol and the characteristics of the amplicon...

If not, then may be there are forward models that predict the amount of the amplified result from the initial content?

Comment: You need to know the primer efficiency for this to work, do you know that?

Comment: @DevonRyan Assume, yes. You can assume I know everything. At this point I want to simply familiarize myself with any such model if there are any.

Comment: Have you considered just using a qPCR calculator such as this http://nebiocalculator.neb.com./#!/qPCRGen ? The model of qPCR is pretty simple really, so there are a few of these premade.

Comment: This is qPCR based on CT number, it is common place to identify patient viraemia for example

Answer (score 1):

The basic equation for PCR kinetics (Equation 1) states that the amount of amplicon after c cycles (Nc) is the starting concentration of the amplicon (N0) times the amplification efficiency (E) to the power c. The PCR efficiency in this equation is a number between 1 and 2 (2 indicates 100% efficiency).  [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2665230/)

In this  [article](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_calculate_the_expected_size_for_amplification_pcr_product_in_a_pcr_reaction)  on research gate they said  [amplifx](https://inp.univ-amu.fr/en/amplifx-manage-test-and-design-your-primers-for-pcr)  was the software you were looking for to, calculate "(i.e. expected efficiency in PCR reaction)". The amplifx even mentions "Testing primers in in silico PCR".